# What's the technique for calling back methods across objects using "send" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm doing some programming that involves asynchronous callbacks in Ruby, and need to pass the callback method to another object (which may or may not be statically called). The issue I have is the syntax of the callback to the instance - I know it's fairly complicated, but I'm not sure I can make it simpler. Here's what I have:

```
class OBJA
  def self.staticMethod(text, returnCall)
    puts "objA.staticMethod: #{text}"
    OBJB.send(returnCall, "Call back from objA.staticMethod")
  end

  def instanceMethod(text, returnCall)
    puts "objA.instanceMethod: #{text}"
    OBJB.send(returnCall, "Call back from objA.instanceMethod")
  end
end

class OBJB
  def starterMethod
    OBJA.staticMethod("foo", :returnedCall)
    OBJA.new.instanceMethod("bar", :returnedCall)
  end

  def returnedCall(text)
    puts text
  end
end
```

You can execute it by doing the following:

```
b = OBJB.new
b.starterMethod
```

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, in most languages it's acceptable to write:  `class A ...end; class B...end`.  We won't get confused. :)

Comment: I added another example that opens up some possibilities, which you may or may not be able to take advantage of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The issue I have is the syntax of the callback to the instance

You have to call an instance method with an instance.  And if you call a class method on a class, e.g.  `OBJB.send(...)`, the class method has to be defined.

```
class OBJA
  def self.staticMethod(text, methName)
    puts "objA.staticMethod: #{text}"
    OBJB.send(methName, "Call back from objA.staticMethod")
  end

  def instanceMethod(text, methName)
    puts "objA.instanceMethod: #{text}"
    OBJB.new.send(methName, "Call back from objA.instanceMethod")
  end
end


class OBJB
  def starterMethod
    OBJA.staticMethod("foo", :returnedCall)
    OBJA.new.instanceMethod("bar", :returnedCall)
  end

  def self.returnedCall(text)
    puts text
  end

  def returnedCall(text)
    puts text
  end
end

b = OBJB.new
b.starterMethod

--output:--
objA.staticMethod: foo
Call back from objA.staticMethod
objA.instanceMethod: bar
Call back from objA.instanceMethod
```

You could also pass blocks to the OBJA methods:

```
class OBJA
  def self.staticMethod(text, &block)
    puts "objA.staticMethod: #{text}"
    block.call("Call back from objA.staticMethod")
  end

  def instanceMethod(text, &block)
    puts "objA.instanceMethod: #{text}"
    block.call("Call back from objA.instanceMethod")
  end
end


class OBJB
  def starterMethod
    OBJA.staticMethod("foo") {|str| puts str}
    OBJA.new.instanceMethod("bar") {|str| puts str}
  end
end

b = OBJB.new
b.starterMethod

--output:--
objA.staticMethod: foo
Call back from objA.staticMethod
objA.instanceMethod: bar
Call back from objA.instanceMethod
```

Or, more illustrative of the closure:

```
class OBJA
  def self.staticMethod(text, &block)
    puts "objA.staticMethod: #{text}"
    block.call
  end

  def instanceMethod(text, &block)
    puts "objA.instanceMethod: #{text}"
    block.call
  end
end


class OBJB

  def initialize
    @x = 1
    @y = 2
  end

  def starterMethod
    OBJA.staticMethod("foo") {puts instance_variable_get(:@x)}
    OBJA.new.instanceMethod("bar") {puts instance_variable_get(:@y)}
  end
end

b = OBJB.new
b.starterMethod

--output:--
objA.staticMethod: foo
1
objA.instanceMethod: bar
2
```

I don't know if this will help you or not, but this trick is used all over the Ruby frameworks.  Ruby being the Wild West of programming languages, it will actually allow you to ignore the closure.  That's useful when you want to accept a block from some code, but you don't want to execute the block in the context in which the block was defined--instead you want to execute the block in a context you create.

```
class OBJA
    @x = 10  #Instance variables attach themselves to whatever object is
    @y = 20  #self at the time they are created.  Inside a class, but outside
             #any defs, self is equal to the class, so these statements
             #create  what are known as 'class instance variables' (@@variables
             #aren't used in ruby because they don't behave 'correctly').


  def self.staticMethod(text, &block)
    puts "objA.staticMethod: #{text}"
    instance_eval &block  #See comment (1) below
  end

  def instanceMethod(text, &block)
    puts "objA.instanceMethod: #{text}"
    block.call
  end
end


class OBJB

  def initialize
    @x = 1
    @y = 2
  end

  def starterMethod
    OBJA.staticMethod("foo") {puts instance_variable_get(:@x)}
    OBJA.new.instanceMethod("bar") {puts instance_variable_get(:@y)}
  end
end

b = OBJB.new
b.starterMethod

--output:--
objA.staticMethod: foo
10  #<--CHECK THIS OUT!!
objA.instanceMethod: bar
2
```

(1) When you call a method without a receiver, ruby uses self to call the method.  Inside a class method, self is equal to the class, so the instance_eval() call is equivalent to:

```
 OBJA.instance_eval &block
```

instance_eval() is used to change the value of the self variable to the receiver.   But self was already equal to OBJA??  What instance_eval() succeeds in doing is changing the value of the self variable that it's block sees!  By converting the block variable to become instance_eval's block, you actually change the blocks context, i.e. the variables that the block's code sees.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment your callback `OBJB.send` is called on the class, but your `returnedCall` method is an instance method. There are two ways to fix this:

Call the callback on an instance instead of on the class by changing lines `OBJB.send(...` to

```
OBJB.new.send(...
```

Or by making the callback method a class method by changing `def returnedCall(...` to

```
def self.returnedCall(text)
```